# How do you complete last stand: roof?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I have just bought the last stand game pack and I'm having trouble with last stand roof. It just happens that I run out of sun due to flower pots and one of my lanes doesn't have enough plants and then the zombies eat my brains. Is there a good strategy for this level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last stand roof is beaten by using the right plants.

- Winter Melon : Awesome AoE DPS and AoE slow
- Melon-Pult : Awesome AoE DPS
- Umbrella Leaf : Protects itself and all other plants arround it
  against Bungee-zombies

The first line should be all Winter Melons, this will make sure that the enemy is always slow. Additional Winter melons are not needed seeing they don't do more damage then regular Melon-Pults

Second line should be Melon, then Umbrella, Melon and then umbrella again and lastly another melon.

Third line should only be Melon-pults

Forth line should be just like the second line.

The massive Aoe Damage in combination with permanent slows will give you the victory while the Umrella's protect against bungees.

Comment: What about defensive plants?

Comment: @MelonPult LAst stand is about killing them before they can do damage if you ask me. So defensive plants are a waste of sunshine

Answer (score -1):

Last stand, as you know, is survival but harder, due to the fact that you cant earn sun.
Roof levels make Last stand so much harder, due to the fact that pots cost a lot of sun.
My strategy for Last stand: Roof was to make Tall-nuts in front, and a torchwood and repeater strategy.
If you can replace tall-nuts fast enough, you can make it!

Comment: Don't forget, that you start out with a bunch (3000-5000) sun so...

Comment: Well, pots get expensive. When I played roof, I didn't really use them unless I had to add new planting areas.

Comment: Try adding more information, "Last stand, as you know, is survival but harder, due to the fact that you cant earn sun. Try to make as little pots as possible, and add as many plants." is not enough and I asked about a strategy not facts. Hope you can improve your answer!

Comment: Alrighty, I added a bunch more! I hope I can help...

Comment: What about the fact that reapeaters cannot shoot over the roofs angle? Where were the reapeaters positioned? e.g. 5 column.

Comment: What? Another version conflict, because I could on my phone...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117180/discussion-between-melon-pult-and-eris-the-guest).